# SHACL: Require sh:property to be a URI

Tags: sparql, rdf, shacl

I was wondering if there's a way to specify that a given `sh:property` is expected to have a value of a URI without any particular class.

In the example SHACL below, the property `meta:value` would only allow URIs, although I don't know of a way to represent it in SHACL.

### Example SHACL

```
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

@prefix meta: <metadata#> .
@prefix meta_sh: <metadata/shacl#> .

meta_sh:Entry
    a sh:NodeShape;
    sh:targetClass meta:Entry;
    sh:property [
        sh:path meta:value;
        # Value expected to be a URI
        sh:minCount 1; # Required; 1 or more
    ];
    sh:property [
        sh:path meta:time;
        sh:datatype xsd:dateTime;
        sh:minCount 1; sh:maxCount 1; # Required; 1
    ];
    .
```

### Example Data

```
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

@prefix meta: <metadata#> .
@prefix data: <data#> .

data:Entry_001
    a meta:Entry;
    meta:value data:ProductListing_459; # URI
    meta:value data:RentalListing_934; # URI
    meta:time "2022-06-15T06:20:31Z"^^xsd:dateTime;
    .
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

@prefix meta: <metadata#> .
@prefix meta_sh: <metadata/shacl#> .

meta_sh:Entry
    a sh:NodeShape;
    sh:targetClass meta:Entry;
    sh:nodeKind sh:IRI ;
    sh:property [
        sh:path meta:value;
        # Value expected to be a URI
        sh:minCount 1; # Required; 1 or more
    ];
    sh:property [
        sh:path meta:time;
        sh:datatype xsd:dateTime;
        sh:minCount 1; sh:maxCount 1; # Required; 1
    ];
    .
```

Comment: shouldn't the `sh:nodeKind` be inside the first property constraint? The goal is to restrict the type of the value

Comment: If the value of the property is of type meta:Entry then no you don't need to specify it inside the property. If it is not, then you can put it inside the property. However, I am not sure if it would be according to the standards or it's really going to work. You can try though, because a property shape is not a node. sh:nodeKind is a constraint for Node Shapes, not Property Shapes.

Comment: I don't get it. The value is the object of the triple with the property `meta:value` - and target class is `meta:Entry` which means the constraints must hold for all instances of that class. So indeed you have to restrict the property constraint to IRI values. I mean, try it online: https://shacl.org/playground/ and modify the data such that there are two values for the property `meta:value` but only of of those is an IRI

Comment: I agree with UninformedUser, You definitely need the sh:nodeKind sh:IRI to be inside the propertyshape, as you are restricting the value that the property can have. A nodeshape cannot have restrictions on values, as it is not targeting properties: it targets classes or individual nodes (subjects), never the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, the `sh:nodeKind` has to be part of the property shape.

The reason why it still not worked: the way you defined the prefixes. They were no full URIs so the SHACL processor added some parts (maybe the disk location of the file, depends). The result: the `meta` in the shapes never matched the `meta` in the data.

This works:

## SHACL

```
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

@prefix meta: <https://example.org/#> .
@prefix meta_sh: <metadata/shacl#> .

meta_sh:Entry
    a sh:NodeShape;
    sh:targetClass meta:Entry;
    sh:property [
        sh:path meta:value;
        sh:nodeKind sh:IRI ;
        sh:minCount 1; # Required; 1 or more
    ];
.
```

## Data

```
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

@prefix meta: <https://example.org/#> .
@prefix data: <data#> .

data:Entry_001
    a meta:Entry;
    meta:value data:RentalListing_934 ; # URI
    meta:time "2022-06-15T06:20:31Z"^^xsd:dateTime;
.

data:Entry_002
    a meta:Entry;
    meta:value "this is not an uri" ; # No Uri
    meta:time "2022-06-15T06:20:31Z"^^xsd:dateTime;
.
```